# Real URL language not working and showing text in a different (not set) language

Tags: typo3, realurl

We last updated our realURL-tool and there is a bug somewhere. The default language of the page is in German with English as a second language.
The problem is now that in some way URL-Tool is working for some pages but not for all.
For example (not a real page)

```
www.example.com/de/home is working fine
www.example.com/de/it is showing some text in the header in spanish
all www.example.com/en/ sites are working fine
```

Here is my realURL configuration:

```php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(
    '_DEFAULT' => array(
        'init' => array(
            'enableCHashCache' => '1',
            'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect',
            'enableUrlDecodeCache' => '1',
            'enableUrlEncodeCache' => '1',
            'emptyUrlReturnValue' => true,
            'autoUpdatePathCache' => '1',
            'respectSimulateStaticURLs' => '1',
        ),
        'redirects' => array(
            'emba' => 'http://www.wiso.uni-koeln.de/en/business-school/executive-mba/?utm_source=print&utm_medium=anzeige&utm_campaign=handelsblatt',
        ),
        'preVars' => array(
            '0' => array(
                'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
                'valueMap' => array(

                    'nc' => '1',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
            '1' => array(
                'GETvar' => 'L',
                'valueMap' => array(
                    'de' => '0',
                    'en' => '1',
                ),
                'valueDefault' => 'de',
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',

            ),


            '2' => array(
                'GETvar' => 'lang',
                'valueMap' => array(
                    'de' => 'de',
                    'en' => 'en',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
            '3' => array(
                'GETvar' => 'type',
                'valueMap' => array(
                    'powermail_cond' => '3132',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
        ),
        'pagePath' => array(
            'type' => 'user',
            'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
            'segTitleFieldList' => 'tx_realurl_pathsegment,nav_title,title',
            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
            'languageGetVar' => 'L',
            'expireDays' => '3',
            'firstHitPathCache' => '1',
        ),
        'fixedPostVars' => array(
            'newsDetailConfiguration' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1array(action)',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        'detail' => '',
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1array(controller)',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        'News' => '',
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1array(news)',
                    'lookUpTable' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'title',
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                            'strtolower' => 1,
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                        ),
                        'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                        'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                        'autoUpdate' => 1,
                        'expireDays' => 180,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

and here is some code from the TypoScript template setup

```
page.headerData.90 >
page.headerData.90 = HMENU
page.headerData.90 {
  special = language
  special.value =  0,1
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    NO = 1
    NO {
      stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
      stdWrap.cObject.value = de || en
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In the preVars section of your configuration there are two entries for language decoding (under index 1 and 2). What happens if you remove the second one? And how is your header in spanish on some pages if your site is only translated to english and german?

Comment: thats exactly what i dont understand. The page is only translated to german and english but somehow my webpage wanted to speak spanish